# Drag to custom trash

Tags: nautilus, trash, drag-and-drop

So, I made this custom trash can.  I want to be able to drag-and-drop files to put them in the trash folder.  This is my desktop file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Trash
Comment=Trash
Icon=user-trash-full
Exec=nautilus trash://
Categories=Utility;
Actions=trash;

[Desktop Action trash]
Name=Empty Trash
Exec=trash-empty
```

How do I make it to where I can drag-and-drop files to the icon to put them in the trash.
Also, maybe add a sound?